# Route not find - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 3.2
```

In my controllers/admin/accounts_receivables_contoller.rb, I have:

```
class Admin::AccountsReceivables < Admin::ApplicationController

  def index
    ...
  end
```

and in one of the views, I have:

```
= link_to admin_accounts_receivables_path
```

In my config/routes.rb, I have:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :accounts_receivables do
    collection do
      get 'admin_report'
      get 'customer_report'
      post 'process_invoices'
    end
  end
end
```

rake routes, produces:

```
admin_accounts_receivables GET admin/accounts_receivables(.:format) admin/accounts_receivables#index
```

However, when I click on the link, I get (in the browser, but no entry in the log file):

```
uninitialized constant Admin::AccountsReceivablesController
```

I do not have a corresponding AccountsReceivable model, as I don't need it.

Any ideas?

Comment: @hashrocket No, see my question

Comment: @hashrocket Please read my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class should be named `AccountsReceivablesController` and you should nest the class explicitly instead of using the scope resolution operator so that it has the correct module nesting:

```
module Admin
  class AccountsReceivablesController < ApplicationController
    def index
      #  ...
    end
  end
end
```

When you use the scope resolution operator `class Admin::AccountsReceivablesController` - the module nesting is resolved to the point of definition which is Main (the global scope) and not `Admin`. For example:

```
module Admin
  FOO = "this is what we expected"
end

FOO = "but this is what we will actually get"

class Admin::AccountsReceivablesController < Admin::ApplicationController
  def index
    render plain: FOO
  end
end
```

See [The Ruby Style Guide - namespaces](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Admin::AccountsReceivables < Admin::ApplicationController
```

should be...

```
class Admin::AccountsReceivablesController < Admin::ApplicationController
```

Comment: I fixed that, and now I am getting another error message: uninitialized constant AccountsReceivable